# Writing a Rails cancan ability using an association, that works with accessible_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Working on an app where a `User` belongs_to an `Organization`. An `Organization` has_and_belongs_to_many Products, though an `organizations_products` table.

I want a `User` with a particular role to be able to manage Products for their `Organization`. In `ability.rb`:

```
def initialize(user)
  # ...snip unrelated stuff
  elsif user.is_manager?
    can :manage, Product, do |product|
      user.organization.products.include?(product)
    end
```

This describes what I want to do but it raises an exception in the products controller:

```
def index
    @products =  Product.accessible_by(current_ability)
end
```

because `acessible_by` [can't be used with blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557091/using-blocks-to-define-abilities-in-cancan-raises-an-exception) in ability definitions. How can I write this ability in a way that is compatible with `accessible_by`?

Answer (score 0):

```
can :manage, Product, user.organization.products do |product|
  user.organization.products.include?(product)
end
```

To clarify: CanCan added the third parameter, which you can understand as a scope to be used by accessible_by, in version 1.6. The block used for evaluating `can :manage, @a_specific_product`, and if you use either of these—the scope or the block—you should probably use both.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532906/1546887), which is mostly a dup of this one, and [the docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks).