# Load models filtered using has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan

I would like to filter models based on a nested resource's attribute, for example:

```
can :read, Model, has_many_relation: { attribute: attr }
```

The problem with using a block of this form:

```
can :read, Model do |obj|
    obj.has_attribute(attr)
end
```

is that the permission can only be used when fetching a single model (the permission is ignored when called to load the #index action).

How can I filter a model using a condition based on a has_many relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter by an attribute un a has_many relation, basic [hash of conditions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) will do.

The first example used to pose the question works:

```
can :read, Model, has_many_relation: { attribute: attr }
```

Just make sure the model has the corresponding has_many relation and that the has_many table contains the column referenced by the attribute:

Answer (score 2):

I've been using CanCan for years, and I only just sorted this out. It's kinda tricky in pseudocode, but hopefully this will get you there.

```
can :read, Model, Model.joins(:has_many_relation).where(has_many_table: { attribute: attr }) do |model|
  model.has_many_relation.pluck(:attribute).include?(attr)  
end
```

A more concrete example (only read widgets in the user's `user.widgets` scope) might be easier to follow:

```
can :read, Widget, user.widgets do |widget|
  user.widgets.include?(widget)
end
```

The general idea is that you have to include *both* a SQL query (for querying all accessible models), *and* a block (for checking permissions on a single model).

And, for the record, the examples we've been looking for are actually already in [the docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks).

Comment: Tried the second solution, but for some reason a missing method error occurs: (undefined method `include?' for #<Widget:0x007fd6968eceb0>). The has_many relation works as expected: when used in rails console the same method works fine.

Comment: It may depend on your rails version. You could replace the `include?` line with anything that would check to see if a specific widget is in the user's widgets scope.

Comment: For some reason it worked only when the query was built using the first format you suggested. Using user.widgets resulted in the 'undefined method `include?`' error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scope if you are using CanCan >= 1.6.

```
can :read,
  Model,
  Model.joins(:has_many_relation)
       .where(:has_many_table => { :attribute => attr })
```

Comment: If you structure a rule like this, `can? :read, Model` gives you `CanCan::Error: The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition. The checking code cannot be determined for :show #<Model...`. So far I haven't found an efficient way to do this.

Comment: You were just missing a block.